# Updating an Array at a specific Index using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of documents in mongoDB. One of the schema's properties has an array, that contains objects. Each object within this array contains a property that has another array as it's value.

```
const userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
  username: "",
  password: "",
  firstName: "",
  clients: [],
});
```

The "clients" property array looks like this:

```
[
    {
      clientName: 'Chabad of Closter',
      activeInvoice: [],
      pastInvoices: []
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Chabad UC',
      activeInvoice: [],
      pastInvoices: []
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Chabad Mobile',
      activeInvoice: [],
      pastInvoices: []
    }
  ]
```

My goal is to push an Object into any of the "activeInvoice" arrays by using the index of its object. I used this code and it works when I specify the index manually:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {"$push": {"clients.2.activeInvoice": newCharge}}, {new : true},
     function(err, updatedCharge){
       if (err) {
         console.log(err)
       } else {
         console.log(updatedCharge);
       }
     });
```

In the example above, I used the "2" index. I need to be able to change that index dynamically. I tried this:

```
 // code to find the index I want and save it to indexer
 const indexer = clientsArr.findIndex(i => i.clientName == newCharge.clientName);
 
 // form it into a string
 const mongooseLink = "clients." + indexer + ".activeInvoice";

 //place it into the mongoose request
 User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {"$push": {mongooseLink: newCharge}}, {new : true},
 function(err, updatedCharge){
   if (err) {
     console.log(err)
   } else {
     console.log(updatedCharge);
   }
 });
```

but this doesn't work. I double checked to make sure the indexer is working. No error, just the document doesn't get updated.

Comment: It should be `{[mongooseLink]: newCharge}` instead of `{mongooseLink: newCharge}`

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) do update in one operation without having to find the index separately